# Infinite loop occuring in binary search, why?

Tags: c, string, binary-search

I've received an assignment to program a dictionary using pointers and memory allocation in C.
everything works fine, but the binary search that I've implemented behaves in a weird way (and I wasn't able to find a certain pattern that causes that behavior):
sometimes after a user inputs a string in `compare` and it is than copied to `search` (after allocation) it just searches without finding but never gets out of the loop, here is the code:
the array that the search uses is sorted and doesn't hold any duplicate values, each element of the array hold an address to a string, I would be grateful for any help.

```
void bin_search (char **word, char **definitions_1 ,char **definitions_2, int limit)
{
   int first, //start value for binary search
   last, //last value for binary search
   middle;  //middle value for binary search
   char compare [81], //will get the word to search
    *search, //will hold the string after memory allocation
    ESC [5] = "Exit"; //this string holds exit value for comparison
 do
  {
        first = 0;
    last = limit-1;
    middle = limit/2;
    compare [81];
    free(search); //memory allocated to search pointer is freed (allocation will take place upon next search)
    printf("Please enter a word (exit to terminate):\n");
    scanf("%s", compare); //gets desired word to search for
    search = (char*) malloc (strlen (compare)+1);
    if (search == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    strlwr (compare+1); //each of the letters (excluding the first one) will be chaneged to lower case letters
    if ((int) *(compare) >= ASCII_a) //if the first [element] letter of a string [word] is a lower case letter
    {
        *compare = (char)(((int) *(compare)) - ASCII_CAPIAL_DIF); //the lower case letter will be changed to upper case one by subtracting the constat difference of 32
    }
    strcpy (search, compare);
        while (first <= last && strcmp (search, ESC) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nsearching\n");
        if (strcmp (word [middle], search) < 0)
        {
            first = middle+1;
        }
        else if (strcmp (word [middle], search) == 0)
        {
            if (definitions_2 [middle] == NULL) //if the word has only one definition, the second NULL one won't be diaplayed
            {
                printf("The word '%s' #%d has 1 definition:\n\n1.%s\n\n", search, middle, definitions_1 [middle]);

            }
            else //if the word has two defenitons - two of them will be disaplayed
            {
                printf("%s\n", definitions_2 [middle]);
                printf("The word '%s' #%d has 2 definitions:\n\n1.%s\n\n2.%s\n\n", search, middle, definitions_1 [middle], definitions_2 [middle]);
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            last = middle-1;
            middle = ((first+last)/2);
        }
    }
    if (first > last && strcmp (compare, ESC) != 0)
    {
        printf("'%s' is an unknown word!\n", search);
    }
} while (strcmp (compare, ESC) != 0);
}
```

Comment: Please show declarations of variables. For example, what is `word`? What is `first`? `last`? What are the values of the involved variables?

Comment: Word is a `char **` variable - the array which contains all of the words after sorting an without duplicate values.
`first` and `last` are variables needed for the binary search to operate.

Comment: Put a few print statements in your code (or debug it) to see how the variables change and where it differs from how you expect it to change.

Comment: Already did, the variables change as expected.

Comment: Better extract the binary search into its own method. That should make everything look better. Also, avoid calling `strcmp` twice for the same arguments, even though some implementations will cache the result.

Comment: Deduplicator, I did as you suggested and it seem to work flawlessly!
the binary search has been extracted to a stand alone function, and the program specific tasks has been written separately.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to look at the structure of the code without all of the details

```
    if (strcmp (word [middle], search) < 0)
    {
        first = middle+1;
    }
    else if (strcmp (word [middle], search) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        last = middle-1;
        middle = ((first+last)/2);
    }
```

Comment: Yep you are right... 
so is it (binary search) implemented correctly?

Comment: @Medvednic At first glance, it appears that your search is implemented correctly, once debugged of course :)

Comment: So what is the problem? I suspect that it has something to do with the user input.
do I have to copy `compare` to another string `search`?

Comment: Copying `compare` to `search` is unnecessary, but harmless. The one problem I see there is that the first time through the loop you call `free` on an uninitialized pointer.  You should initialize `search` to NULL, or just remove it altogether.